# Display data from database with using COLUMN not row in CodeIgniter VIEW

Tags: database, codeigniter, view, html-table

I have problem in my view display in codeigniter

I have a problem with my database display in the 'view' in CodeIgniter, I've been able to do load my database and display data using tables, but the data is performed by using extends vertically downwards by using a row, whereas I want to display it horizontally by using **column**

*[my view display in browser]*
[data 1]
[data 2]
[data 3]
[etc...]

**my view I wanted!**
**[data 1] [data 2] [data 3] [etc..]**

this is my Controller Code:

```
function coba(){
    // nyobain nge load td secara multiple
$data['query'] = $this->Latihan_model->coba()->result();
$this->load->view('rubbish/coba',$data);
}
```

this is my model Code:

```
function coba(){
$sql = ("
    SELECT soal.ID_soal as soal
    from soal
    where soal.ID_bagian = 1;
    "); return $this->db->query($sql);
}
```

this is my view code:

```
<table border=1>
<?php foreach($query as $post): ?>
<tr>
    <td><? echo $post->soal; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I hope you're understand what I am asked

Comment: Move the `tr` outside foreach?

Comment: I input my answers. Wish that will help for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
<table border=1>
<tr>
<?php foreach($query as $post): ?>
    <td><? echo $post->soal; ?></td>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php foreach($query as $key => $value): ?>
<tr>
   <?php foreach($key as $val): ?>
       <td><?php echo $val; ?></td>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```